# How to format a JSON/XML answer from a REST call using jQuery or any other thing?

Tags: jquery, json, xml, rest

I have an HTML that invoke a REST webservice and get the JSON/XML answer.
What I have to do to get the answer on readable way?
Could I use some ajax to not refresh the page? How?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Specify Parameters</title>

  <script>
    function execute() {
      var param1 = $("#param1").val();
      var param2 = $("#param2").val();
      var format = $('input:radio[name=format]:checked').val();
      var url = "http://localhost/something?rs=" + param1 + "|" + param2
              + "&format=" + format;

      location.href = url;
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mainDiv">   

    <div class="param1">
    <label for="param1">Param1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="param1" size="10" value="514" />
   </div>   

   <div class="param2">
    <label for="param2">Param2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="param2" size="10" value="PI761" />
   </div> 

<div id="radioButtonsDiv">
     <input type="radio" name="format" value="json" checked>JSON
     <input type="radio" name="format" value="xml">XML
</div>

<div class="submitDiv"><input type='button' id='submit' onClick='execute()' value="Submit"/><div class="submitDiv"> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Response example:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "string01": "104",
        "string02": "104 - blablabla",
        "string03": "104",
        "string04": "blobloblo",
        "string05": "blablabla",
        "dest": [{
            "pred": [{
                "time": 1461348846,
                "sec": 102,
                "min": 1,
                "string11": "514-String",
                "string12": "Some String",
                "string13": "Some other String",
                "number": 0
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: What technology/language are you going to use to do this? JavaScript?

Comment: Try knockout. If you go through _the first step_ of this tutorial http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections it'll teach you to do exactly what you need.

Comment: I edited my question @SergiuParaschiv i still don't know how exactly I can get the JSON/XML text to be able to format it.

Comment: After the jquery.ajax call you'll get that data as a JS object. Then you go the knockout route with it and display it.

Comment: what jquery.ajax call? I just using location.href = url; and getting an JSON/XML response.

Comment: That won't work. You need to load that response in the same page and display it. 'Window.location' is like clicking on a link, you don't/can't control whatever is displayed after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the output in HTML format using jQuery like this:

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
    $('#divname').html(data.result[0].string05 + ',' + data.result[0].dest[0].pred[0].time);
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divname"></div>
```